# How to create vtkImageData using vtkImageImport that persists after vtkImageImport deletion?

Tags: c++, c, vtk

I have a simple C pointer containing some RGBA image data that I want to use as `vtkImageData` to add as a texture on a `vtkActor`. To do this I have some code like

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> myActor; // initialized elsewhere

setActorTexture( unsigned char* pData, int width, int height )
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData;

    if( pData )
    {
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport> imageImport = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport>::New();
        imageImport->SetWholeExtent( 0, width - 1, 0, height - 1, 0, 0 );
        imageImport->SetDataExtentToWholeExtent();
        imageImport->SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();
        imageImport->SetNumberOfScalarComponents( 4 );
        imageImport->CopyImportVoidPointer( pData, width * height * 4 );

        imageData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
        imageData = imageImport->GetOutput();
    }

    if( imageData != nullptr )
    {
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTexture> texture = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTexture>::New();
        texture->SetInputData( imageData );
        myActor->SetTexture( texture );
    }
}
```

Sadly, this causes a memory exception when the image data is later used in rendering. It appears that the `imageData` object becomes invalid once `imageImport` object goes out of scope.

How can I stop the `imageImport` object deleting itself when it goes out of scope? The `texture->SetInputData()` and `myActor->SetTexture()` functions register their parameters such that the `vtkObject`s have their reference counts correctly set. I think I need to do something so that the `imageImport` also has its reference count set correctly to  reflect the need of `imageData`.

Comment: What happens if you put `vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport> imageImport;` before `if( pData)` ?

Comment: No change. The `imageImport` object still goes out of scope at the end of the function and is deleted as it's ref count isn't high enough

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to DeepCopy the Output?

```
setActorTexture( unsigned char* pData, int width, int height )
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData;

    if( pData )
    {
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport> imageImport = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport>::New();
        imageImport->SetWholeExtent( 0, width - 1, 0, height - 1, 0, 0 );
        imageImport->SetDataExtentToWholeExtent();
        imageImport->SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();
        imageImport->SetNumberOfScalarComponents( 4 );
        imageImport->CopyImportVoidPointer( pData, width * height * 4 );

        imageData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
        imageImport->Update(); //important
        imageData->DeepCopy( imageImport->GetOutput() );
    }

    if( imageData != nullptr )
    {
       vtkSmartPointer<vtkTexture> texture = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTexture>::New();
       texture->SetInputData( imageData );
       myActor->SetTexture( texture );
    }
}
```

Note that id did not test this code, but it should work. You need the update before deepcopying so that the ImageImport actually does its job.

Answer (score 0):

this does not seem to be an issue with the vtkImageImport itself, rather that the rendering pipeline does not accept RGBA images.

Documentation for vtkImageImport::SetNumberOfScalarComponents() states that there should be 3 components specified (for RGB images): https://vtk.org/doc/release/7.1/html/classvtkImageImport.html#a6f505565fa53cd850e95256deb22275d

Thus loading 4-component image and stripping the Alpha component using vtkImageExtractComponents, as follows, might help:

```
setActorTexture( unsigned char* pData, int width, int height )
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> imageData;

    if( pData )
    {
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport> imageImport = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageImport>::New();
        imageImport->SetWholeExtent( 0, width - 1, 0, height - 1, 0, 0 );
        imageImport->SetDataExtentToWholeExtent();
        imageImport->SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar();
        imageImport->SetNumberOfScalarComponents( 4 );
        imageImport->CopyImportVoidPointer( pData, width * height * 4 );
        imageImport->Update();

        // remove alpha channel
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageExtractComponents> extract = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageExtractComponents>::New();
        extract->SetComponents(0, 1, 2);    // RGB components
        extract->SetInputData(imageImport->GetOutput());
        extract->Update();

        imageData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
        imageData = extract->GetOutput();
    }

    if( imageData != nullptr )
    {
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkTexture> texture = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTexture>::New();
        texture->SetInputData( imageData );
        myActor->SetTexture( texture );
    }
}
```